# How do I render a list from Json data in express js, then render it using react and map()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I had a question, and a problem when rendering Json data with react js. I Couldn't get react to map out the data. Here is my code:

My Json:

```
res.json({
    list: [{id: 1, name: 'Caleb'}, {id: 2, name: 'Isaiah'}]
})
```

My React Code:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
  
function App() {

  const [data, setData] = useState({})

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/home")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => setData(data))
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
        {data.list.map(function(d, idx){
         return (<li key={idx}>{d.name}</li>)
       })}
    </div>
  );
}
  
export default App;
```

Its giving me this error, that it cant render it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve your goal is to use conditional rendering (&&), you can put the JSON data in a variable, but it's not necessary. Another improvement is to use the object id as the key and not the index.

Here's an example of how to improve your code:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/home")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => setData(data))
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      {data.list && (
        data.list.map(function (d) {
          return <li key={d.id}>{d.name}</li>;
        })
      )
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Hi, It didnt work after I plugged it in.```

Comment: Nothing Shows Up, It doesn't give me any errors, but it doesn't render the data.

Comment: It worked great! Once i plugged it in right! It didn't work at first, but the reason was i had changed a few things with the Json data, so it wasn't grabbing the right thing! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by first putting the Json data into a variable, then made sure that the variable wasn't undefined, then rendered it! Like this:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
  
function App() {

  const [data, setData] = useState({})

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/home")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => setData(data))
  }, [])

  const new_data = data.list;

  const renderAuth = () => {
    if (new_data !== undefined) {
      return (
        <div>
          {new_data.map(function(d, idx){
            return (<li key={idx}>{d.name}</li>)
          })}
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      console.log("sorry had problems")
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {renderAuth()}
    </div>
  );

}
  
export default App;
```

Then it worked like a charm! No problems at all.